C# ASP.NET Core MVC controller function OkObjectResult got different behaviors with or without async in function defition
We are troubleshooting the following sample program in an ASP.NET Core MVC controller class.
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpPost("TestFunction")]
    public Task<IActionResult> TestFunction()
    {
        return Ok("OK");
    }

This code results in a compiler error

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>'

However, if we add async to the function definition and make it
public async Task<IActionResult> TestFunction() { ... }

the error disappears.
We wonder why.

Because the async keyword automatically returns a Task. Instead, you should return Task.FromResult because it is lightweight.

The Ok() method returns an OkObjectResult type, which implements IActionResult. If your method were not async at all, and the return type was defined as IActionResult, you could return this OkObjectResult and it would compile, as it is possible to convert the OkObjectResult type to IActionResult.
With the async keyword present, the function will "wrap" returned results in a Task object, thus making the type Task<OkObjectResult>, which is convertable to Task<IActionResult> which is the defined return type of your method. More info on this process here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types
Without the async keyword, you're attempting to return an OkObjectResult, but your method's return type is defined as Task<IActionResult>. Hence the error.

Thank you for your answer. And, for the case without async, we made it work by also removing the Task<> wrapping around IActionResult. So, the function looks like public IActionResult TestFunction() { return Ok("OK"); }.
